# javascript - setters and getters enigma ... Why does it function?

Tags: javascript, json, getter, setter

Look at the simple code below, I can set "t.map.text.color" to "yellow" without ".map".

How is it possible?!?

```js
class Text {
    constructor() {
        this.map = {};
        this.map.text = { color: 'red' }
    }
    get text() { return this.map.text; }
}

const t = new Text();

t.text.color = 'yellow';     // WHY DOES IT FUNCTION??
console.log(t.map.text.color); // yellow
```

Comment: Thats what the `text` getter does.

Comment: `get text() {
      console.log('text() called');
      return this.map.text; }
      }`

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a *reference* to the object `{ color: 'red' }`.
The getter is essentially the same as writing

```js
getText() {
  return this.map.text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of your getter function, that points to this.map.text.

You're essentially doing `t.text()` which returns a pointer to `t.map.text`

By doing `t.text().color` (with the [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) you can just do `t.text.color`), you're pointing to `t.map.text.color` and assinging it the `"yellow"` value

Comment: So, the "result this.map.text" in my gettter create the link, and it functions even if i'm setting a value (and not getting) ....

Comment: No, every assignment in javascript is by reference, so the getter is not doing any link, the getter is simply returning "directions" to where the value is stored in memory, by calling `t.text` the getter is returning the **same object, not a copy** of `this.map.text`, so you can in fact change stuff there and you'd be modifying **the same object** in memory

Comment: google `Difference between a Value Type and a Reference Type`

Comment: Yes i know. My question was about i was doing a set and not a get. So this all is possibile because the "result" in my get. If i change the result to something else (eg: return('Color', this.map.text.color)) i don't have the same result. Don't you?

Comment: you do, it will just reference a String type, which has different attributes and operations, but is still an object. Try making a getter for `this.map.text.color`, let say `get color()`, you then do `t.color = 'color'`, then do an operation like `t.color.replace("o", "a")`, the value will be modified. The difference is that `this.map.text` is an object, which has the `color` attribute, and all the object functions